# Where are the Ubuntu Core Snappy images?

Tags: 15.04, 16.04, ubuntu-core

So the final release announcement has been made by Canonical but the Ubuntu Snappy Core images are nowhere to be found. Previously they could be found under 15.04 at releases.ubuntu.com now that is throwing a 404 and there are no new images under 16.04.

Meanwhile, my 15.04 machine running is refusing to update. `sudo snappy update` defaults without any messages and without doing anything. I'm open to this being a bug in my neglected install, but maybe there is more to it.

Is anyone currently running Ubuntu Snappy Core 16.04 and how the heck did you get there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that some automatic cleanup tools got it and deleted old snappy images. Meanwhile, you can use http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-snappy/15.04/stable/latest/ which isn't wiped out :)